# PWI - Picasa Webalbum Integrator and jQuery.noConflict()?

Tags: gallery, picasa, jquery

I have a Problem with the following script: http://code.google.com/p/pwi/

*This is a very nice Picasa jQuery Gallery!*

Can someone please tell me how i run this script in `jQuery.noConflict()` mode? I have already added the line...

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict()</script>
```

...in the HTML file and replace all ***$*** with ***jQuery***. But then the script doesn't work anymore.

---

Nobody can help me? I have the Demo 1 from [this ZIP file](https://code.google.com/p/pwi/downloads/list)
with fancybox.

Normally i need only replace ***$*** with ***jQuery*** in the .html and .js files, and then add the ***jQuery.noConflict()*** to the head. But here doesn't work...

The error console in Firefox says:

> Error: TypeError: n.gphotojQuerytimestamp is undefined
>
> Source file: file:///C:/Users/pc/Desktop/jquery.pwi/js/jquery.pwi.js
>
> Line: 361

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page from jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) you can use two methods.

I did a quick test, and it looks like you can use the second method. If you modify Demo1 like this:

In the script section where PWI is initialized add these lines before `var $viewerSelected = "fancybox";`:

```
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
```

Just before the closing end-script tag add the lines

```
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
```

This at least makes sure that the code is still running without errors